# Vertical alignment in a tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest

I've used `base=bottom` and `base=top` to have the text in a child node vertically aligned. However, I don't have the desired output. I would like to have "You can" in front of the edge, not "if you".

Here is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={forked edge, anchor=center}
        [,phantom,s sep=1cm
            [example, for tree={grow'=east}
                [You can\\if you\\try hard, align=left, base=bottom]
                [child2]
                [child3]
                [child4]
                [child5]
            ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the child anchor (where the line connects) relative to the anchor `base` of the relevant node, which you can achieve by redefining the default `edge path` for `forked edge`:

```
edge path'={
    (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(\forestoption{fork sep},0) |- ([yshift=.5ex].base west)
}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={forked edge, anchor=west, edge path'={
            (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(\forestoption{fork sep},0) |- ([yshift=.5ex].base west)
        }}
        [,phantom,s sep=1cm
            [example, for tree={grow'=east}
                [You can\\if you\\try hard, align=left]
                [You need\\to adjust, align=left]
                [child3]
                [child4]
            ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]